# Linear Regression without Least Squares in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am working with the *LinearRegression* module from *sklearn.linear_model* and I want to compute the parameters of my Linear Regression model **without using Least Squares**.

For example, I would like to estimate this parameters by minimizing the values from one of the regression metrics defined in module *sklearn.metrics* (for instance, mean_squared_log_error).

Is there a module that will allow me to easily do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own cost function and call minimize. Be aware that there are no constraints on `minimize`, so you may want to add some on top of what I'm showing here:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
from scipy.optimize import minimize

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([100, 200, 300])
```

So here is the model I want to learn (i.e. the regressor):

```
def fun(x):
    return a*x
```

Now here is my cost function:

```
def cost(x):
    return mean_squared_log_error(b, fun(x))
```

And now I can optimize it:

```
print(minimize(cost, x0=[1]))
```

Be aware that I don't provide a gradient here, so can be slow (or using numerical differences IIRC with some optimizers).